# i need assistance with some TAB code, Jquery

Tags: jquery

So long story short, im working with some jquery tabs and im using this code.

```
css of the tabs:

/* ---------- INNER CONTENT (ACCORDION) STYLES ----*/
.accordian {    
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:20px auto;   
    color:red;
    overflow:hidden;

}

#boxOut{
    width:320px;
    height:410px;
    overflow:scroll;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:154px auto auto 38px;

}






/*.accordian {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
*/
.accordian li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 8px;
}

.dimension {
/*  height: 400px;
*/}


.odd, .even {
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 27px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    background: #ececec;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 8px; 
-moz-border-radius: 8px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
margin-left:6px;
margin-right:6px; 

}

.logo{
    width:300px;
    margin:6px auto;
}

.intownLogo{
    width:255px;
    margin:6px auto;
}

.spaces{
    margin-top:8px; 
}
```

js:

```
   $(function() {
        // Hide all the content except the first
        //$('.accordian li:odd:gt').hide();
        $('.accordian li:odd').hide();


        // Add the dimension class to all the content
        $('.accordian li:odd').addClass('dimension');

        // Set the even links with an 'even' class
        $('.accordian li:even:even').addClass('even');

        // Set the odd links with a 'odd' class
        $('.accordian li:even:odd').addClass('odd');

        // Show the correct cursor for the links
        $('.accordian li:even').css('cursor', 'pointer');

        // Handle the click event
        $('.accordian li:even').click( function() {
            // Get the content that needs to be shown
            var cur = $(this).next();

            // Get the content that needs to be hidden
            var old = $('.accordian li:odd:visible');

            // Make sure the content that needs to be shown 
            // isn't already visible
            if ( cur.is(':visible') )
                return false;

            // Hide the old content
            old.slideToggle(500);

            // Show the new content
            cur.stop().slideToggle(500);

        } );
    });
```

My jquery is noobish at best so although i undestand what its doing, i cant edit it without breaking it...lord knows ive tried lol.

The part im having problems with is that, with these tabs, although they work, they work with the .next() functions etc, so when a tab is open, if i click the same tab to close, it doesn't close, it only closes when another tab is clicked.

What im needed help with is ....something that says

"logic" if this tab is already open and is clicked, close the current open tab.
so that said, for example, based on the code above

pseudo code coming:

```
if ( cur.is(':visible') && cur.is(':clicked') )
        cur.slideToggle();
```

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) event.  It's simple - you pass it functions as parameters.  Each function is run in turn as you click on the target.  A simple example:

```
cur.toggle(
    function()    //function 1
    {
        cur.show();
    },
    function()    //function 2
    {
        cur.hide();
    }
);
```

The first time you click, it runs the first function, executing `cur.show();`. The next click runs the second function, running `cur.hide();`.  Another click runs the first function again, and so on and so on.  You can even add more functions, so you have specific functions on the 1st through nth clicks, over and over.

Comment: Hey surreal, Thanks for looking at this. maybe i shoulda put that in there but, ive tried this and this is what happens, if i just put "cur.toggle(function(){ cur.show()}) by itself, then itll open, but when i click to hide, it animates the hide then reopens, when i add it exactly like you have it, it doesnt do anything. it just stays there with all tabs closed.

Comment: There must be other code acting on the tabs then.  If you have `cur.toggle(function(){ cur.show()})` then there is no reason for the tab to close on click - it would try to show on every click.  Some other code must be giving it the instruction to `.hide()`.

Comment: lol well thats where im stuck at lol. like i said b4, i know 100% what you mean but if you look above, thats literally all the code to the tabs, evens and odds being attached to the tabs h1(s) and thats it. i think the key is in the " $('.accordian li:even').click( function()" but, what i tried is inserting your slideToggles into that function and nothing. ive tried other events and again nothing....and like i said b4, the code above is the only code for these tabs. everything else on the micro site i coded up so im sure

Comment: you know what, nvm, i said  F-it and just wrote my own function and delete what mess this was lol. thanks for the tip